# The first, the last, and everything between

Tags: code-golf

Given two integers, output the two integers, and then the range between them (excluding both).

The order of the range must be the same as the input.

#### Examples:

```
 Input        Output
 0,  5   ->   [0, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
-3,  8   ->   [-3, 8, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
 4,  4   ->   [4, 4]
 4,  5   ->   [4, 5]
 8,  2   ->   [8, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
-2, -7   ->   [-2, -7, -3, -4, -5, -6]
```

Comment: I guess we can't take the inputs in pre-ordered order?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, no, the output order depends on the input order

Comment: @StewieGriffin, the output order has to be the same as the input

Comment: Is [this](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38rUR03z//9qAx0F01oA) output format acceptable? Note the newline

Comment: @LuisMendo I'll allow it :)

Comment: I assume a space or newline delimited string is also allowed as output, instead of an actual array/list/stream?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Any reasonable I/O is acceptable.

Comment: The spec (which just uses the word "between") seems to allow the repetition of the extremities of the inclusive range, but the examples assume that this range is exclusive. So is `2 5 2 3 4 5` actually a valid output for `2,5`? (I think people have just been assuming "no").

Comment: Is it acceptable if we take input in strictly reversed order? so e.g. `[5,1] -> [1,5,2,3,4]` and `[1,5] -> [5,1,4,3,2]`. Basically, it preserves that the input order matters, and it gives the correct result for a pair of "first input" and "second input", but the actual input format is `[second,first]`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan No ;)

Comment: @KamilDrakari That's okay

Comment: Can I do something like `(0,5,(1,2,3,4))`?

Answer (score 16):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>39</s> <s>33</s> 30 bytes

```r
c(a<-scan(),setdiff(a:a[2],a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYpBCsIwEEX3nmLAzQxMQGLFIt16CnExxI4ENIUmBUU8e0wiLlz9x3t/zgqDAV2CS34K@OAnvSA6CX@aXCuwPt6XmyQfrt@PTjOkMVaRHcpgqkXiOKaLV0U5yMmeWYjye6W4YdhRWbNlgL5SV6D7QWt9AdtOlsHsKX8A)

Thanks for saved bytes to user2390246 and J.Doe.

Comment: You could [save a few bytes](https://tio.run/##NcdBCoAgEADAe6/wuAsKZUoS/UQ8LNaCF4Oy95sG3WauymJTlZ8cSzozEEYgeR9lT8xAfgoreR0kIVaGCKMUwiIO3WpucV9Mk/lhO1yD7tBSqAXrCw) by taking the input as a vector rather than as two separate integers.

Comment: Yeah, that's reasonable, and it actually then becomes even shorter as a full program rather than function.

Comment: You can abuse the fact the `:` operator uses the first element of both args for [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYpBCsIwEEX3nmLAzQxMQGLFIt16CnExxI4ENIUmBUU8e0wiLlz9x3t/zgqDAV2CS34K@OAnvSA6CX@aXCuwPt6XmyQfrt@PTjOkMVaRHcpgqkXiOKaLV0U5yMmeWYjye6W4YdhRWbNlgL5SV6D7QWt9AdtOlsHsKX8A "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 13):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
Ÿ¦¨«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6I5Dyw6tOLT6//9oCx2jWAA)

**Explanation**

```
    Ÿ      # inclusive range [a ... b]
     ¦¨    # remove the first and last element
       «   # append to input
```

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>52</s> <s>48</s> <s>47</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:[a,b,*range(a,b,-(a>b)|1)[1:]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7NCsIwEITvPsWAl0Q20L80paAvUnNI0aqgtZReBN89blJ/6iFhNvPtZIbHdL73ue@2e391t/bg4KitG75oM7r@dBRBKuF2rXymsklra/0wXvpJdAIJAVpKrNGw1ISUkBFyQmFXH0rxiGqmgq4IiiHFbLLciAElwfxWwyOKebX4C42O/jp64XA@stmpYriJsTp@kS96hRLm3StqPlxEMaaYVqX1Lw)

---

Combined former implementations.

Comment: You can remove the space at `or-1` to save a byte.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2 (Cython)](http://cython.org/), <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```python
lambda x:x+range(*x,-cmp(*x)|1)[1:]
```

*Thanks to @nwellnhof for golfing off 1 byte!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpBDoIwFAXXeoq3A/Q3gYqRNNGL1C4QrZJIaRoW3yBnr0DcvJlknv8Mr95J0ayMFmdc47vubvcarHgfavd8pDsm0XR@ZvYtMl0oE20fwGgddE44GoIWB0K1SEko/1xDRZDrQRLEyajtxofWDbDJyDo3Sk6E2YrFAIjLPKNNOZuS@AM)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

```python
lambda x:x+range(*x+[-cmp(*x)|1])[1:]
```

*Thanks to @JonasAusevicius for the port to CPython!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpBDoIwFAXXeoq3IbTym9CKkZDoRWoXKIIkUgiy@CbevVbiZt4kb6b38hi9CS1OuIRnPVybGlxxNte@u4sdZ1bdhimK/Ggnra5caMcZjN7D5oSDI1i1J5Q/KQjFf9ejJJg1MAR1dNV2M829X5AmpiFEAFDniOSVIoFgm8ecrY5sBUsZvg)

Comment: This can be applied to standard Python 2 at 37 bytes, making it the shortest answer yet: `lambda x:x+range(*x+[-cmp(*x)|1])[1:]`. Nice solution

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>26</s> 22 bytes

```perl6
{|@_,|[...^](@_).skip}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/usYhXqcmWk9PLy5WwyFeU684O7Og9n9xYqVCmkaNSrymQlp@kYKGgY6CqaaOgoausY6CBYhhoqNgAqXBEhY6CkZgBUY6Crrmmv8B)

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                    }
 |@_,   # Slip args a,b into result
      [...^](@_)  # Reduce args a,b with ...^ operator, same as a...^b
                .skip  # Skip first element
     |  # Slip into result
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:[x,y]+range(x,y,-(y<x)|1)[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp9IqGkjEahcl5qWnagCZOroalTYVmjWGmtGGVrH/C4oy80oU0jQy8wpKSzQ0daC05n9dYy4LAA)

Comment: Really like `-(y<x)|1`. very cool but I can't work out why it works! Any chance you can explain it?

Comment: @ElPedro Basically, `y<x` checks if `y` is strictly less than `x`, and returns `True` if it is, `False` otherwise. After that, unary `-` is applied to it, which converts `True` to `-1` and `False` to `0`. The last step is to bitwise OR this number with `1`. This obviously leaves `1` (`0b1`) unaffected, and also leaves `-1` (`-0b1`) unaffected (the sign bit of `-1` is set, so it's kept as such). However, it does convert `0` to `1`, so that `range` doesn't complain about me using a `step` of `0`.

Comment: That is seriously cool and very clever. If I could upvote twice I would. Many thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 6):

## Japt, 8 bytes

```
cUr!õ kU
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=Y1VyIfUga1U=&input=WzgsMl0=)

```
             :Implicit input of array U
c            :Concatenate
 Ur          :  Reduce U by
   !õ        :   Inclusive range
      kU     :  Remove all elements in original U
```

Comment: The 5-byte version seems to now fail for the ```4,4``` test case...

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>47</s> <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:[a,b]+range(a,b,a<b or-1)[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8kqGkjEahcl5qWnagCZOok2SQr5RbqGmtGGVrH/C4oy80oU0jQUDHQUTDW5YFxdYx0FCwRXwURHwQSVi6RYwUJHwQhJr5GOrrnmfwA)

Here's mine, now that a lot of other Python answers have been posted

<sub>-6 bytes, thanks to G B</sub>

Comment: Taking advantage of the empty range when it's invalid is a smart way to deal with forward or backwards lists. I could see that being very useful and is a nice trick to know exists.

Comment: 41 bytes using a single range: range(a,b,(a<b)*2-1)

Comment: `a<b or-1` is shorter for the 3rd range parameter. The shortest I got was `lambda x,y:[x,y]+range(x+(x<y or-1),y,x<y or-1)`

Answer (score 6):

## **Python 3, <s>64</s> <s>62</s> 51 bytes**

`lambda a,b:[a,b]+[*range(a+1,b)]+[*range(a-1,b,-1)]`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBPi8IwEMXvfoqHp3adgLX/pNCDF0HYw4LHmEOK7W5BG2l78dN3J0NZu2Agyczk994keTzHH9fFU1Neppu9V1cLS1WheTEb/dHb7rsO7CaiKlzkinNSUWimsR7GASX0Cjy03lJqCLwhJUSEHSEmJMbQDChO9x6RgKCYYDtsl7ioM0L@0iXehWXJPzdPztX0VWXbna/uxTAXq1Rs48VFfONcbiIRT26tGFLMqsyTZtW4HgF/RkgObQd5biEObYNGTlCWcAUefduNwfrrcD4Xa5pFcDRToYjq21D/ocfD6fMtOv0C)

## **Python 2, <s>58</s> 45 bytes**

`lambda a,b:[a,b]+range(a+1,b)+range(a-1,b,-1)`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZA/C8IwEMV3P8XDqcUL2NpaKXRwEQQHwbFmSLHVgjbSdvHT18tR/4GBJHeX33uX5P7oL7YJhyo7DldzK04Ghoo050XPWtOcS8/MAir8V6I4IRX4Q192fYcM@QQ88nxOsSbwhpgQEELCghBpTSOgOF05RAKCYoLdMP/GRb0kJB9d5FxYFv24OXKsxp8q24auuhLDRKxisV18XcQ1TuQmEvHk1oohxaxaOlJPKtvC42/wyaJuIM9NxaGuUMkJsgw2xb2tm96b7teHQzqlUQRLI@WLqLx25RvdrLe7v@jwBA)

Comment: Because an empty list is falsey, you can remove the `a<=b and ` from both answers

Comment: You could also use `+` instead of `or `

Comment: Python 3 down to 47 bytes: `lambda a,b:[a,b,*range(a+1,b),*range(a-1,b,-1)]`

Answer (score 5):

## Java 10, <s>109</s> <s>108</s> <s>104</s> <s>102</s> <s>93</s> 62 bytes

Using a space-delimited String:

```java
b->a->{var r=a+" "+b;for(;a<b?++a<b:--a>b;)r+=" "+a;return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZAxb4MwEIV3fsUpExa2VaWpGtWBbpU6dMpYdTgTiEyJQfaBFEX8dmooUsrW5fSe3539@SrsUVSn7zGv0Xv4QGNvEYAnJJNDFVLZkall2dmcTGPl2yIO75aKc@H4/5qO5Iw9ZxmUkMKoRYYiu/XowKWYbGCTaFU2LlZ40K9JEuqLEJhpxVySTjEqV1DnLDg1jCoKiG2n64C4kPaNOcEl0Me/L31@AbLpJwBUeIof@BNTdyse@f6v3/Hd2q6693y7Gt5y8TwfDNF9VzPBnBtLgHyqekE4Xj0VF9l0JNtAR7WNS4ltW19jzRaBbLlyGH8A)

Using a List:

```java
b->a->{var r=new java.util.Stack();for(r.add(a),r.add(b);a<b?++a<b:--a>b;)r.add(a);return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lZAxa8MwEIX3/IobLSKJkqY0VIm7FQrt5LF0ONtykOPIRjq7hODf7iquS@Ixy/Ge7km8TyV2KMr8MGQVeg@faOx5AeAJyWRQhq1syVSyaG1GprbybRLbd0t6rx2/N/RhPMUxFLCDIRUxivjcoQO3s/rnJpYQZoeIqaJ2kZOY5xEy/idSpnCbvi6XYb4IgXGq2H9EOU2ts@BUP6hFIGnatAokE1BXmxyOATJKyBm7//oGZBdgANKeogf@xNTVike@ufVrvp7bWXrDV7PLKy6ex4N@cf3SscG4N5YA@WWmU4Xk5EkfZd2SbEI7qmxUSGya6hSYJ4FserIffgE)

(`a<b?++a<b:--a>b` can be `++a<b||(a-=2)>b` for the same byte-count: [Try it online for the String](https://tio.run/##jZAxb4MwEIV3fsUpky1sK6KpGsmBsVKGThmrDmcCkSkxyBxIUcJvp0CRUrYup/f87s6fXWCHsjh/D2mJTQMfaN09AGgIyaZQjKlqyZYqb11KtnLqfRGHo6Psknnxv6YTeesuSQI5xDAYmaBM7h168DGGG9iERueVZzoM8WAeD4YyjnhiNPdhPMWofUatd@B1P@hgRKxbU46IC2lX2TNcR3r2e9PnFyCfXgJAWUNsK165flr5IvZ//U7s1nbVvRfRajgS8m0@6IPnX80Ec24dAYqpmgXhdGsou6qqJVWPdFQ6lius6/LGDF8E8mVlP/wA) or [Try it online for the List](https://tio.run/##lZAxb4MwEIV3fsWNtmKsiKZqJAfGSpXaibHqcICJTIhB5qCKEn47dShVkrGL9Z7v@fQ@VzhgWBWHKa@x6@ADjT0HAB0hmRwqP5U9mVqWvc3JNFa@LmL3ZknvtRP/Db2bjpIESohhysIEw@Q8oAMXW/19F0sJ8wPjqmwccxKLgiEXvyLjarXCXXa5MAzjiCeZ4n8R5TT1zoJT46QCT9L2We1JFqChMQUcPSRLyRm7//wC5FdgANIdsbV45upmwyexvfcbsXm0D@mtiB4eRyJ8mS/G4Palc4N5biwBiuuZLRXSU0f6KJueZOvbUW1ZKbFt65NnXgTyZeU4/QA).)

---

**Old (<s>109</s> <s>108</s> <s>104</s> <s>102</s> 101 bytes) answer using an array:**

```java
a->b->{int s=a<b?1:-1,i=a!=b?(b-a)*s+1:2,r[]=new int[i];for(r[0]=a,r[1]=b;i>2;)r[--i]=b-=s;return r;}
```

-7 bytes thanks to *@nwellnhof*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZAxb8IwEIV3foW72a1tkZSqCOOgLpU6dGKMMpwhQabBiewLFUL89tSkkShbF@vevTv5fbeHI4j99qvf1BAC@QTrzhNCAgLaDdlHV3Zoa1l1boO2cfJ9LJYfDstd6fn/hqzDvMgyUhFNehCZEdk59kjQsDSrZCESbjU8aLOiRgB7DE/JIuU@L7Qrv4dtW6iq8dTn00JDdJJCG2WzVDGfC2GjEjooX2LnHfHq0qtJBGk7U0eQkefY2C05REa6Rm/dLi8IsCsvIVgGpFP@wtRNimc@/6tnfHYv76bnPL1bTrl4HRqXye2iQ4LBv9IDv75mjLA@BSwPsulQtjEd1o7ebvvmPZyCxOY3Oa0ktG19osDGwjA2/nbpfwA)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->b->{                // Method with 2 int parameters & int-array return-type
  int s=               //  Step integer, starting at:
        a<b?1          //   1 if the first input is smaller than the second
        :-1;           //   -1 otherwise
      i=               //  Array-index integer, starting at:
        a!=b?          //   If the inputs aren't equal:
         (b-a)*s+1     //    Set it to the absolute difference + 1
        :              //   Else:
         2,            //    Set it to 2
      r[]=new int[i];  //  Result-array of that size
  for(r[0]=a,          //  Fill the first value with the first input
      r[1]=b;          //  And the second value with the second input
      i>2;)            //  Loop `i` downwards in the range [`i`,2):
    r[--i]=            //   Decrease `i` by 1 first with `--i`
                       //   Set the `i`'th array-value to:
           b-=s;       //    If the step integer is 1: decrease `b` by 1
                       //    If the step integer is -1: increase `b` by 1
                       //    And set the array-value to this modified `b`
  return r;}           //  Return the result-array
```

Comment: Isn't there anything in Java's standard library for making ranges of integers? Or it is just too verbose to use?

Comment: @Οurous It's indeed too verbose: `a->b->{var L=java.util.stream.IntStream.range(a,b).boxed().collect(java.util.Collectors.toList());L.add(0,b);L.add(0,a);return L;}` (130 bytes)

Comment: Is it Java 8 or Java 10 ? Because of "var" ^^'

Comment: @Neyt Ah, fixed. My initial version with the array below didn't use `var`, which is why I usually put those at 8, and the ones that does use `var` as 10 (and the ones using `String.repeat` as 11). :) Forgot to update it after adding the List and String answers, should be corrected now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
,œ|r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/n6OSaov@Hlxvpu///b6CjYKqjoKBrrKNgAaRNdEAIhEGiQBEjkCSQ0DUHAA)

#### How it works

```
,œ|r  Main link. Left argument: a. Right argument: b

,     Pair; yield [a, b].
   r  Range; yield [a, ..., b].
 œ|   Perform multiset union.
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 51 bytes

Takes input as `(a)(b)`.

```javascript
a=>g=(b,c=b)=>(b+=b<a|-(b>a))-a?[...g(b,c),b]:[a,c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bczBCsIwEATQu1@yg0koVbFIN35I6WE3tkEpjdjiyX@PepQIc3rDzE2esoTH9b7aOV2GPHIW9pFJTWAFe9ItaysvS@oFsHLunHPx28Nof@rEhD6HNC9pGtyUIo1UgQ7A5hftDtQUuscnf7DcN6C6PK1B9gjkNw)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                // main function, taking a
  g = (             // g = recursive function
    b,              //     taking b
    c = b           // we save a backup of the original value of b into c
  ) =>              //
    (b +=           // add to b:
      b < a |       //   +1 if b is less than a
      -(b > a)      //   -1 if b is greater than a
    )               //   (or 0 if b = a)
    - a ?           // if the updated value of b is not equal to a:
      [             //   generate a new array:
        ...g(b, c), //     prepend all values generated by a recursive call
        b           //     append the current value of b
      ]             //
    :               // else:
      [a, c]        //   stop recursion and return the first 2 values: a and c
```

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 5 bytes

Anonymous infix function.

```apl
,,…~,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY6xDoIwFEV3vuJ9wHsJQgudXFxkMhE3w0ACuBBlcNDFmJgwmEB0cHR15R/4lP5IfXSqLm16e87NzZuainNeH3ZUno7lvigLYxD19XNBU@n2obte969kpe@3cQh1@@RXul7wuVkmqQG/ApAAoLs3zfne@ggSYYYQIIQIIvPYY0i5EPGPQiBmiFHfFawfIcSZB4JF4YrCNtpc/uWSc8V54ObK1sa2UNrycBoUVDAO8c@iaQpz0zJijJimKPsC)

`,` the first and last (lit. the concatenation of the arguments)

`,` and (lit. concatenated to)

`…` the range

`~` without

`,` the first and last (lit. the concatenation of the arguments)

Comment: Nice, so I assume you're going to be using this for all of your golfing from now on?

Comment: @Zacharý Probably only if the code is *significantly* shorter or simpler.

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 45 bytes

```matlab
@(a,b)[a b linspace(a,b,(t=abs(a-b))+1)(2:t)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1EnSTM6USFJISczr7ggMTkVJKKjUWKbmFSskaibpKmpbaipYWRVohn7PyWzuEAjTcNAx1RTkwvK0TXWsUDwTHRMkDlI6ix0jJA0Genommtq/gcA)

Comment: IF the first is larger than the second, the range must be descending

Comment: Oh man, I can't read

Comment: I ended up changing the language

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 34 bytes

```
a#b=a:b:[a+1..b-1]++[a-1,a-2..b+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYlLCoQwEAWv0uAmId3BZBRF8AieIIShMwwoapA4Lub08bN5RdUbeZ@/y5IzF6HnLnSOldE6kPFKOSaDTPZyZXxeeYrQw8rb8AaxpSn@QMMRP0dKfxCFlOBEibVEQS9sL1RYPXunFu19WKRG@nwC)

Comment: This does not work. GHC interprets `b-1` as `b $ (-1)`. Use `b- 1` instead.

Comment: @MarkNeu: it does work. See TIO link.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I had `NegativeLiterals` on.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 26 bytes

```
,,[|.@]^:(>{.)<.+1}.i.@|@-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/dXSia/QcYuOsNOyq9TRt9LQNa/Uy9RxqHHT/a3IpcKUmZ@QDVacpmEKY8cZAtgWEbQJkmiCYUBUWQKYRVLERkB1v/h8A)

### Explanation:

A dyadic verb (takes left and right argument)

```
                         -    subtracts the arguments
                       |@     and finds the absolute value
                    i.@       and makes a list 0..absolute difference
                 1}.          drops the fist element
                +             adds to the entire list
              <.              the smaller of the arguments
   |.@]                       reverses the list
       ^:                     only if
  [                           the left argument
         (>{.)                is greater than the first item of the list
 ,                            appends the list to
,                             the right argument appended to the left one
```

Comment: `,,[:}.@}:<.+i.@-@(+*)@-` for 23 bytes and no special casing on relative argument ordering (rather: it's hidden inside the signum `*`).  i feel like this could get down under 20 but i'm tired.

Comment: @Jonah Thank you! Btw FrownyFrog's solution is way better than mine, so I 'm not going to golf it any further.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 13 bytes

```
,,<.+i.@-~-.=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/dXRs9LQz9Rx063T1bP9rcilwpSZn5AMVpCmYQpjxxkC2BYRtAmSaIJhQFRZAphFUsRGQHW/@HwA)

```
     i.@-~       range [0 .. |difference|-1], reverse if the difference is positive
          -.=    remove the zero (either "=" is 0 or there’s nothing to remove)
  <.+            to each element add the smaller of the args
,,               prepend args
```

Comment: Nice solution! I totally forgot about`i.` with negative argument.

Comment: this is gorgeous!

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>33</s> 40 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{[a,b]+[*a..b,*a.downto(b)][1..-2]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6k6GkjEakdrJerpJekAyZT88rySfI0kzdhoQz09XaPY2v8FCmnRCgY6CgqmsVwgtq4xkG0BYSuYANkmSGyoGgULINsIqt5IR0HXPPY/AA)

Temporary fix, trying to find a better idea

Comment: For `[4,4]` this gives only one `[4]`

Comment: You are right, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 107 bytes

```
@echo %1
@echo %2
@for %%s in (1 -1)do @for /l %%i in (%1,%%s,%2)do @if %1 neq %%i if %%i neq %2 echo %%i
```

Takes input as command-line arguments. Explanation:

```
@echo %1
@echo %2
```

Output the two integers.

```
@for %%s in (1 -1)do
```

Try both ascending and descending ranges.

```
@for /l %%i in (%1,%%s,%2)do
```

Loop over the inclusive range.

```
@if %1 neq %%i if %%i neq %2
```

Exclude the two integers.

```
echo %%i
```

Output the current value.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>52</s> <s>47</s> 41 bytes

```python
lambda i,j:[i,j]+range(i,j,(i<j)*2-1)[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFTJ8sqGkjEahcl5qWnagCZOhqZNlmaWka6hprRhlax/wuKMvNKFNI0DHRMNblgHF1jHQsEz0THBJmDpM5CxwhJk5GOrrnmfwA)

-5 with thanks to @JoKing

-6 by slicing the first element from the range (idea stolen from and with credit to @TFeld)

Non-lambda version...

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>51</s> <s>49</s> 47 bytes

```python
i,j=input();print[i,j]+range(i,j,(i<j)*2-1)[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfnJ@SqmCroK6u/j9TJ8s2M6@gtERD07qgKDOvJBooEqtdlJiXnqoBZOpoZNpkaWoZ6RpqRhtaxf4H6uFKrUhN1gCZoall9t9Ax5RL11jHgstExwSITbksdIy4dI10dM0B)

-2 with thanks to @JoKing

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
+QtrF
```

Input is a two-element list, `[input 1, input 2]`. Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BQtrF&input=%5B0%2C5%5D&debug=0), or verify all the test cases at once [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BQtrF&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%2C5%5D%0A%5B-3%2C8%5D%0A%5B4%2C4%5D%0A%5B4%2C5%5D%0A%5B8%2C2%5D%0A%5B-2%2C-7%5D&debug=0).

```
+QtrFQ   Implicit: Q=eval(input())
         Trailing Q inferred
   rFQ   Generate range [input 1 - input 2)
  t      Discard first element
+Q       Prepend Q
```

Comment: Using `F` instead of `.*` on 2-element lists is a brilliant trick that I will absolutely be using from here on.

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 75 bytes

```
func[a b][s: sign? d: b - a prin[a b]loop absolute d - s[prin[""a: a + s]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcvBCoQgFIXhvU9xcBvCUA0TbnqHtnIXmjoEodGt57em1bj8@c7Zgy9T8IZE1CWeaTYWjgxr8PJNI7yGg4LFti/psTXnDdZxXs8jwN/I5kEprb6HDZiISsQLb/GDA1KKCNVh@O8efZ3VekBbnVuoT7kA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 49 bytes

```
import StdEnv
@a b=init[a,b:tl[a,a+sign(b-a)..b]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4zLIVEhyTYzL7MkOlEnyaokB0glahdnpudpJOkmaurpJcXG/g8uSQRqsFVwULBQ0DX6/y85LScxvfi/rqfPf5fKvMTczORiAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 29 bytes

```apl
{⍺,⍵,(⌽⍣(⍺>⍵))(⍺⌊⍵)+¯1↓⍳|⍺-⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhOpHvbt0HvVu1dF41LP3Ue9iDSDfDsjX1ASxHvV0gdjah9YbPmqb/Kh3cw1QUBcoVPv/v4FCmoIp16H1xkDagssESJqASVMuCyBpBJQxAtKH1psDAA)

A port of my `J` solution

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised this is so long for a seemingly simple task.

Comment: @Quintec Probably it can be golfed, or maybe another algorithm will result in much shorter solution.

Answer (score 3):

## TI-BASIC, <s>35</s> 34 bytes

-1 byte from [Misha Lavrov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/74672/misha-lavrov)

```
Prompt A,B
Disp A,B
cos(π(A>B
For(I,A+Ans,B-Ans,Ans
Disp I
End
```

Comment: And one more byte by replacing `1-2(A>B` with `cos(π(A>B`.

Comment: @MishaLavrov `seq(` wouldn't work for inputs where `A` and `B` are the same, unfortunately :(

Comment: True - also, I left out an argument of `seq(`, so I'm no longer convinced it even is smaller. Still, the `cos(` trick should help.

Answer (score 3):

### PHP (102 bytes)

```
function t($a,$b){count($r=range($a,$b))>1?array_splice($r,1,0,array_pop($r)):$r=[$a,$b];print_r($r);}
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/870c42af9617a26dda4cc80cca4aebf17f215b6d)

Unfortunately (for golf) PHP has rather verbose function names, which contribute a lot to the length.  But the basic idea is to create a range, then pop off the last element and stitch it back in at offset 1.  For the `4,4` example I had to add `count($r=range($a,$b))>1?...:$r=[$a,$b];` which adds quite a bit, and unfortunately `array_splice()` is by reference which hit me for a few more bytes (`$r= and a ;`). All because of that "edge case", lol.

Well anyway enjoy!

Comment: I dont think that this is a right approach for code golf. Check this one 
`function t($a,$b){$o=array($a,$b);for($i=$a+1;$i<$b;$i++)$o[]=$i;print_r($o);}`

Comment: Or something like this `function t($a,$b){echo $a.$b;for($i=$a+1;$i<$b;$i++)echo $i};`

Comment: It has to be a function and it has to output an array.  If you have a better answer your more then welcome to post it.

Comment: I edited it, is that a valid submission now? Shall I put it as a new answer or what?

Comment: That is entirely up to you, I just wanted to do it without a loop ... lol

Comment: It's embarrassing but my code doesn't even hold up for reverse range. so never mind

Comment: I see that.... :-(

Answer (score 3):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 61 bytes

```clj
(fn[[a b]](def s(if(> a b)-1 1))(list* a b(range(+ a s)b s)))
```

An anonymous function that takes a 2-vector as input and returns a list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY2xCsIwFEV3v@KOL9pCaxEKgl/g4B46pDXRSE20SQS/Pibd2tXhweVw7n3DaB9hkjGSMpwL9F1HV6ngSCs6IQFW1qgZo1E7v82AJmFuknYpO9anYyzOHYW/RhiOOEufZuQ7iBH@LiGMNd@nDQ4qmMFrayB6@5Ebek3a@NGkl@AVDt1cv2QIRbwqMlpaZYN2pZVNkdnSa7FfaW2RUfwB)

### Explanation

```clj
(fn [[a b]] ; An anonymous function that accepts a 2-vector as input, and destructures it to a and b
  (def s (if (> a b) -1 1)) ; If a > b assigns -1 to s and assigns 1 to s otherwise. This determines the order of the elements of the output list.
  (list* a b ; Creates a list with a and b as the first two elements. The remaining elements will be appended from the following range:
    (range (+ a s) b s))) ; A range starting at a+s and ending at b with step s
```

Answer (score 3):

## [D](https://dlang.org/), 85 bytes

```d
T[]f(T)(T a,T b){T[]v=[a,b];T c=2*(b>a)-1;for(T i=a+c;a!=b&&b!=i;i+=c)v~=i;return v;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBDoIwEAXQNZxi2JBWClHESNLUU3RHWLQgySRCTa11QfDqlbhSFpP8vPw/fQiyaQciKZGgmARN5xW8aBTTLZfQiXJH9EXR/MAHY9cWCpV1XCVCp6lOBHLMREf9e0326p52As@X4A32MCqcCIU5jnC8G@vg4fpiPTQ8jgayZydavCy66236Qn5k9b9UrNrCZlOzcvOkZJCff2wJHw)

A port of @HatsuPointerKun's C++ answer into D.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 73 bytes

Without recursion:

```
(s,e,m=s>e?-1:1)=>[s,e,...[...Array(m*(e-s||1)-1)].map((_,i)=>s+m*(i+1))]
```

Try it:

```js
f=(s,e,m=s>e?-1:1)=>[s,e,...[...Array(m*(e-s||1)-1)].map((_,i)=>s+m*(i+1))]

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(0,5)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(-3,8)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(4,4)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(4,5)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(8,2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(-2,-7)));
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
ＩＥ²ＮＩ…⊕θηＩ⮌…⊕ηθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQMNIR8Ezr6C0xK80Nym1SEMTCKy5kNQEJealp2p45iUXpeam5pWkpmgUauooZGAoSy1LLSpOxaI8A6i8EGzs///RukDrdM1j/@uW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＩＥ²Ｎ
```

Print the inputs on separate lines.

```
Ｉ…⊕θη
```

Print the ascending range, if any.

```
Ｉ⮌…⊕ηθ
```

Print the reverse ascending reverse range, if any.

Answer (score 2):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), <s>85</s> 84 bytes

```
f(a,b)=>[a,b]+((a-b).abs()>1?List.generate((a-b).abs()-1,(i)=>(a>b?-i-1:i+1)+a):[]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBDoIwEAXQvadgOZPOEIsYCcRyAW9AWExjMV3YmNKd8ewVd9jVT97P/3eJKecFhCxezbTFrACELdZiV0Cjx5tfU/1wwUVJbt@xJvDbCsTYkT3r3iuNSrCfZhzyU3wAfB@q6hV9SLDAkc6Iww74RN2/tNSWUGw6aoqThvjyo0/@Ag)

-1 by going from `>=` to `>`

Answer (score 2):

## QBASIC, <s>39</s> 53 bytes

```
INPUT a,b
?a
?b
FOR q=a+1TO b-1 STEP SGN(b-a)
?q
NEXT
```

Added the `STEP` parameter to account for `a>b`, and that uses the `SGN()` function to get a -1 or a +1 as increment. This however breaks the REPL because the `SGN()` function isn't implemented there...

[Try it (the old answer) online!](https://repl.it/@pimsteenbergh/ConsciousStaleDevice)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 65 bytes

```c
f(a,b){for(printf("%d %d",a,b);a<b?++a<b:--a>b;)printf(" %d",a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU5LDsIgEF3DKSZNTECGWGuNRqoepLKgP8NCNBU3Nj17haqbmffLm6nlta6nqWMGKz509549eut8x5JFA4smwagrU1RnIcI8SGlOleL/0DfC1TgFDjdjHeMwUPL0xtsaouhLXWYajlEmKcIWw5YbhH0EOUL@27OxR8jmQIYgd5SMipLwFbBYZY@pAls87bu9d8zz1Q8tPQ@6EPNpEpzS6jLVCDNYax5KyP/li0siHynpW//qHaSKjtMH)

Not very exciting. The loop increment is borrowed from an early version of Kevin Cruijssen's Java answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, 41 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)$a;$b;$a..$b|?{$_-notin$a,$b}
```

Less golfed test script:

```powershell
$f = {

param($a,$b)
$a                # push $a to a pipe
$b                # push $b to a pipe
$a..$b|?{         # push to pipe all integers from $a to $b
    $_-notin$a,$b # ...except $a and $b itself
}

}

@(
    ,( 0,  5  ,   0, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4)
    ,(-3,  8  ,   -3, 8, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
    ,( 4,  4  ,   4, 4)
    ,( 4,  5  ,   4, 5)
    ,( 8,  2  ,   8, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3)
    ,(-2, -7  ,   -2, -7, -3, -4, -5, -6)
) | % {
    $a,$b,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $a $b
    "$("$result"-eq"$expected"): $result"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: 0 5 1 2 3 4
True: -3 8 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
True: 4 4
True: 4 5
True: 8 2 7 6 5 4 3
True: -2 -7 -3 -4 -5 -6
```

Explanation:

The basic concept of Powershell is the pipe. Pipe is an array. All results that push into the pipe fall into the array. So we should just push the values into the pipe in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <strike>739</strike>, 555 bytes

```
 public static List<Integer> firstLastAndEverythingBetween(final int a, final int b) { if (a == b) { return addAB(a, b); } final List<Integer> result = addAB(a, b); int initial = getInitial(a, b); for (int n = 1; n < Math.abs(b - a); n++) { result.add(initial); if (b > a) { initial++; } else { initial--; } } return result; } private static int getInitial(int a, int b) { return (b > a) ? (a + 1) : (a - 1); } private static List<Integer> addAB(int a, int b) { final List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(); result.add(a); result.add(b); return result; }
```

Comment: This reminds me of my first post on here (in LUA). You should really make an effort to atleast remove the white space. I'm no Java programmer, but even I can see some quicky areas for golfing. Consider taking a look at this before the negative votes start piling up. Also, there is a templated style for posting code with the language name and number of bytes as a heading. I'd incorporate that. Here is a link to an online byte counter https://mothereff.in/byte-counter

Comment: Ok, learning about hte Code golf, I will do better with time

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Good to have you with us :)

Comment: Good first effort. You'll soon learn the tricks. First one is to delete all of the unneeded spaces and shorten all variable and function names to one letter. Just the kind of things you wouldn't do in "real life" (hopefully!). Welcome on board.

Comment: How do I compile this? [Simply putting it in a main class](https://tio.run/##fVJNb8IwDD3Dr/AxqCsS10GZirQDEjvtOO3gULeEdQElpgih/nbm0HbQCe0Uf7w8Pz95ixXGuz3ZbfZ12R90adawLtF7eENj4dzVPCPLszKeZ0vLVJCbQ26c5xV6Tm32WpE78cbYYkF8JLIqNxZLMJYBn@CW6BGcweSgEJKkyRzxwVnALEsXSsB6NIW6/dKf6MgfSoakjw20xho2gk@gIF42SdfPdw5UAFlpT6byzGQ93oxRe6UhBhSQjaJGS5gwFn7VUoYBIlfDXHBBe1OOoiCSSk@3WhyHWt0t1HCF0t6ZCpk6G4OWO5mtR7/utN@7kS/BqwgmI3gOUSzRA86@UY0/f4n/tdTSEVLn8HTtz5UMuTMD@6m@pv0tL4P@sVQ7k8G3nJF6ZyeH8fEJ6AovQoaDelhffgA "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online") doesn't seem to work.

Comment: ah it is a method: then if you use main copy and paste this code below your main method and call it as a method.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>53</s> 48 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to @mypetlion.

```python
lambda a,b:[a,b,*range(a+1-2*(a>b),b,1-2*(a>b))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBLq8IwEIX3/oqDq1YnoH1YKVRwIwh3ccFlzSLFVgvaSNuNv75OhuIDDCSZTL5zZpL7o7/YJhyq7Dhcza04GRgq0pwXmrWmOZeemS9VMPPMpvA5@Yp9PfRl13fIkE/AI88XFGsCb4gJS0JACAmR1jQCio9rh0hAUEwoBhefuKhXhOSti5wLy6IvN0eO2fidZdvAZddimIhVLLbhRyOucCKdSMSTSyuGFLNq5Ug9qWwLj3/CJ4u6gTw3FYe6QiU3yDLYFPe2bnpv@r89HNIpjSJYGilfROW1K1/obrv/@4kOTw)

Comment: Save 5 bytes with starred expression to unpack the `range` object `lambda a,b:[a,b,*range(a+1-2*(a>b),b,1-2*(a>b))]`

Answer (score 2):

### C++, <s>143</s> 140 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#define V std::vector<int
#include<vector>
V>f(int a,int b){V>v{a,b};int c=2*(b>a)-1;for(int i=a+c;a!=b&&b!=i;i+=c)v.push_back(i);return v;}
```

How to use :

In the main function :

```cpp
std::cout << f(0, 5) << '\n';
std::cout << f(-3, 8) << '\n';
std::cout << f(4, 4) << '\n';
std::cout << f(4, 5) << '\n';
std::cout << f(8, 2) << '\n';
std::cout << f(-2, -7) << '\n';
```

also add :

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v) {
    os << "[ ";
    for (const auto& a : v) {
        os << a << ' ';
    }
    return os << ']';
}
```

Comment: You can chance the `auto` to `int`, as well as using a `#define` for `std::vector<int>`

Comment: `#define V std::vector<int`, and replace `V f` with `V>f` and `V v` with `V>v` for -1 byte.

Comment: Suggest `c=b>a?1:-1` instead of `c=2*(b>a)-1` and `a-b&&b-i` instead of `a!=b&&b!=i`

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 60 bytes

```c
f(a,b,c)int*c;{for(*c++=a,*c++=b;(a<b?++a<b:--a>b);*c++=a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7LTsMwEDwnXzGKhGR311IIRa3qpv2Q0sPaEGSpBFRyq/LtYZ0IysWzs/NYRxcv0r9PU2eEA0eb@mEV/a37vJpVJGqFZwjeyD4cifTdOSeHYP2iWz9OGsLw9j2YPAgjQ7C3sshDPDX12ZdFvoDAiFZJUoa2XVyFEOluVI@ezZmEFrVX2EN9B4QjBA5hh6AgFoRHlYnm@NdVM52pHl5Raf8pne1S9yu89JVuxjJXf0jqTY7NH64Zz9k8E/fE2P6xNWP9n9x9W0ZzDzUMt8n10w8)

Comment: Can ditch the parens in the middle argument of `for()`

Answer (score 2):

## APL(NARS), 14 chars, 28 bytes

```
{⍺⍵,¯1↓1↓⍺..⍵}
```

test

```
  f←{⍺⍵,¯1↓1↓⍺..⍵}
  ¯3 f 8
¯3 8 ¯2 ¯1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
  0 f 5      
0 5 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](http://haskell.org), <s>18</s> 34 bytes as function, <s>46</s> 52 as an IO action, <s>56</s> 62 as program

```
x!y=x:y:[x+1..y-1]++[x-1,x-2..y+1]
```

or, as an IO action to take input, there are these options (all the same length):

```
main=(\x y->x:y:[x+1..y-1]++[x-1,x-2..y+1])<$>readLn<*>readLn
--
x!y=x:y:[x+1..y-1]++[x-1,x-2..y+1]
main=(!)<$>readLn<*>readLn
--
f x y=x:y:[x+1..y-1]++[x-1,x-2..y+1]
main=f<$>readLn<*>readLn
```

or, as an IO action taking input and printing the result:

```
main=((\x y->x:y:[x+1..y-1]++[x-1,x-2..y+1])<$>readLn<*>readLn)>>=print
--
x!y=x:y:[x+1..y-1]++[x- 1,x-2..y+1]
main=((!)<$>readLn<*>readLn)>>=print
--
f x y=x:y:[x+1..y-1]++[x-1,x-2..y+1]
main=(f<$>readLn<*>readLn)>>=print
```

The last one is also available on [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM89WQyOmQqFS167CqtIqukLbUE@vUtcwVls7ukLXUKdC1wjI1zaM1bRRsStKTUzxybPRgjI07exsC4oy80r@/zfgMgAA)! (You can try it online there)
Please remember that TIO requires the input be entered beforehand in the "Input" box.

De-golfed:

```
enumerate' x y = x : y : [x + 1 .. x - 1] ++ [x - 1 , x - 2 .. y + 1]
main = do x <- readLn
          y <- readLn
          print (enumerate' x y)
```

Note: `:` is an operator to prefix an element to a list.

Note: `a!b` will not work if `-XBangBatterns` is enabled.
Use `a#b` instead.

Note: `-XNegativeLiterals` will break this. Insert a space between `x-` and `1`.
This will parse as `x + (negate 1)` instead of `x $ (-1)`.

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that your shortest solution is essentially the same as [nimi's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175505/).

Comment: Oh, sorry. Should I remove this?

Comment: You don't need to. According to [this consensus on Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/56433), duplicate answers are fine.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 86 bytes

```cs
x=>y=>{var l=new List<int>{x,y};for(int s=x>y?-1:1;x!=y&(x+=s)!=y;)l.Add(x);return l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc7BC4IwFMfxe3/F8hDvkUpakbS2iKBDdOvQWXTGQCZssybi327WwbPBO3wffA6/zASZkb2xqZUZudQqO0hl/TFu0thvcM5JQVjvGG8Yb1@pJiVT4k1G0Dq/6WhRaRg@YpjjzTGI9hF1c9YswC2ZwaEoluEpz8Eh1cLWWpGSdj2dzc6VMlUpwoeWVtykEnC3WqpneK2kAo94fgErhC0i0kk4WCMkk/UGh/sDT9@RIMTTR8cIwe7H@w8)

-1 thanks @auhmaan!

Comment: You can save a byte by replacing the `&&` with a single `&`; Also, since your answer isn't for `C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)` you need to add to your byte count the `using`s - which is `System.Collections.Generic` for this solution, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I've updated my answer. I kind of like this compiler better :)

Comment: It also lowers your byte count a lot

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 75 bytes

```
(a,b,n=-~(a>b?a-b:b-a)-2)=>[a,b,...[...Array(n<2?0:n)].map(_=>a<b?++a:--a)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BCoMwFESv4jLB/4OklooYpecIofxYU1psIrEUu@nV09jFzMA8hnnQm9Yx3pcX@nCdklOJEVjwCr@MejsQ2tYicZRc9XpHQgiddY6RPsx3cqhaz4140sIuqqfODmVJLeaNSS5EthXBFVpXcDSg8QBNjhrqv@9VA3IHEvBkDB@DX8M8iTncmGP5Z@M8/QA)

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY3dasMwDIXv9xS6tKlk0vw0ITQJfQ5jhtw1paWzSzpG9/Sp7DHYhSxxzneOr/zNj@NyuX9RiB@ndR5WxegxDDz6icn3nlgPo02iMcbKHJaFf1TYl1PRB9pqZz75rt6Hkfd@2my4J4m4dY6LekKcwdoCG4eWKuxk1VjnN0kdlskokVrn9DGGR7ydzC2e1azkp6fWq4UCoUHYIpQIFUIN7s2ClEGHIFEgsYr/QOZ3CG0m679I0vPRZbLNTJP56rczlYmcuklUEpN2Yr0A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
+¹ht…
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8b/2oZ0ZJY8alv3//z862kDHNFYnWtdYxwJImeiYgEmQkIWOEUjCSEfXPDYWAA)

Thanks to Dominic Van Essen for the fix.

Comment: I'm afraid I think you'll need to use [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8b/2oZ0ZJY8alv3//z862kDHNFYnWtdYxwJImeiYgEmQkIWOEUjCSEfXPDYWAA) to pass the ```[4,4]``` test case...

Answer (score 1):

## C# .NET Core, <s>56</s> 441 bytes

Here is my corrected solution without predefined input variables and without string joining.

```
(a,b)=>n(a,b).c(k(a-b)>1?b>a?r(a+1,b-a-1):r(b+1,a-b-1).i():n());
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVHRSsMwFH3fV1yGDwm2wT7sZV07RKYoCmMKPow@JDHbwrp0JulQRr@93m4T7YaKEBLuyTkn9@RKF8rCqrp02szh8d15tWL32rzGnRZ0VeS5kl4XxrEbZZTVss2IO@tS5FqC89zjIXPuHIzevDKuUW070Cbcjky5UpaLXA2eUpC4Eb/Q7viCB8eIoJAgjj0ZyT0RNP7DW//ofXCaqI2yThF0qj5z7AOMT/q@Lo0caOMDwC2FJSTwwP2CXQoX/8pt52jEKVhUf4Fsws1cnbggdZqBIWtu@codykPrJ@RNoV@wIW2I8xbH01Dt3FHAIIA/5gp859lqr3DKipx1p7DdM9ldgapuALhmBF9hY958SiOfXmR0F@I7FmWU0gqybjOA6t/ZZ5DUhAeCJqnZnUySJeGhoGk0FCkfWsLPo0CEPIxo3xKBBd5iwTShfUMojeuqrnt17wM)

```
n(a,b)               => returns new array with a and b in it
  c(                 => concat the following content
    k(a-b)>1         => when absolute value of a-b greater then one
      b>a            => when b bigger a
        r(a,b-a)     => range from a to b-a
        r(b,a-b).i() => else range from b to a-b reversed
      n()            => else empty array
```

I've created and used the following declarations. When I include those and the minimum code required to compile in the byte count I get 640 bytes.

```
public static class Extensions{
  public static IEnumerable<T> c<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b) => a.Concat(b);
  public static IEnumerable<T> i<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a) => a.Reverse();
}

public static Func<int, int> k = Math.Abs;
public static Func<int, int, IEnumerable<int>> r = Enumerable.Range;
public static int[] n(params int[] a) => a;
```

---

```
using System.Linq;using System.Collections.Generic;using System;public static class E{public static IEnumerable<T> c<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a,IEnumerable<T> b)=>a.Concat(b);public static IEnumerable<T> i<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a)=>a.Reverse();}public class P{public static Func<int,int> k=Math.Abs;public static Func<int,int,IEnumerable<int>> r=Enumerable.Range;public static int[] n(params int[] a)=>a;public static void Main(string[] args){Console.WriteLine($"[ {string.Join(", ", f(int.Parse(args[0]), int.Parse(args[1])))} ]");}public static Func<int,int,IEnumerable<int>> f=(a,b)=>n(a,b).c(k(a-b)>1?b>a?r(a,b-a):r(b,a-b).i():n());}
```

Comment: What exactly are your "tricks"?

Comment: @FireCubez all the declarations which aren't in the body. Is that allowed?

Comment: Which body? Take a look at the [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default). If it isn't there then it's allowed

Comment: @TFeld I've corrected it. It's just not that nice anymore^^

Comment: You dont' need all the string join stuff, returning a list is okay (it looks funny for input `4,5` :P)

Comment: @TFeld Thanks for the info. I also corrected the `4,5` case and have now 87 bytes.

Comment: One of your 'tricks' seems to be taking input through predeclared variables, which is not allowed as it turns this into a snippet. Additionally, pre-declaring functions is also not allowed. Submissions should be either self containing functions or full programs.

Comment: Other than that, welcome to PPCG. Don't be too discouraged, I hope you stick around!

Comment: @JoKing Thanks for the info and the welcome. I've just added a second solution without predefined input variables. I hope this is what you ment. I still have declarations for method aliases.

Comment: Err no, the method aliases aren't allowed either, unless you include the declarations in your answer

Comment: @JoKing And therefore they are part of the byte count or can I just mention them as I did now?

Comment: You have to include it in the bytecount

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85539/discussion-between-jo-king-and-ntfrex).

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 85 bytes

```
proc R a\ b {puts $a\n$b
if $a>$b {lassign $a\ $b b a}
while {[incr a]<$b} {puts $a}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzNCsIwEITv@xRDyTUgtcUexIfo1XrYBH8CMYam4qHss8dVxMPA/PDN4mOteX54jOAJDmt@LgWGp2QchYu6g9E2cinhmj4DNDuw0OsW4hnrMSQ/g0974@SPi9R45/z7pA16slsM1KFT9TSgJdvC7kiZUQF9pS/bNFLf)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 97 bytes

```
a=>b=>[a,b,...((c,d)=>c==d?[]:(s=(m=Math).min(a,b),Array(m.abs(a-b)-1).fill().map(n=>++s)))(a,b)]
```

Can probably be improved!!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 57 bytes

```python
def m(a,b):s=(1,-1)[a>b];return[a,b]+list(range(a+s,b,s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFXI1EnSdOq2FbDUEfXUDM60S4p1rootaS0KC8aKBOrnZNZXKJRlJiXnqqRqF2sk6RTrKn5v6AoM69EI1dDwUBHQcFUU5MLJqBrDBSwQBJQMAEKmKALIGtRsAAKGCGbYaSjoGsOtAUA)

Comment: Same approach down to 49 bytes: `def m(a,b):s=1-2*(a>b);print(a,b,*range(a+s,b,s))`

Answer (score 1):

**JAVA 147 bytes**

```
f(int a, int b){System.out.print(a+""+b);if(a<b){for(int i=a+1; i<b;i++){System.out.print(i);}}else{for(int i=a-1;i>b;i--){System.out.print(i);}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 68 bytes

```
(define(f a b)(let([s(if(> a b)-1 1)])(list* a b(range(+ a s)b s))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@a@ck5iXrlAE4WikpKZl5qVqpCkkKiRpauSklmhEF2tkpmnYgQV0DRUMNWOB4pnFJVogEY0ioOZUDW0gu1gzCYiBAGhIZnFBTmKlAtAYAwVTTU0uuIhSTJ4SEheoQNdYwQK/ChMFEwoVWCgYEXCEkYKuOdDlAA)

The same as TheGreatGeek's `Clojure` solution

Answer (score 1):

## perl -M5.010 -alE, 58 bytes

```
@_=($F[0]..$F[1],reverse$F[1]..$F[0]);say"$_ @_[1..$#_-1]"
```

This reads two integers (on a single line, separated by whitespace) from `STDIN` and writes the result to `STDOUT`.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 62 bytes

```
a=($(seq $1 $2|tr $'\n' ' '))
echo $@ ${a[@]:1:((${#a[@]}-2))}
```

### explanation

`seq` does we want but produces lines, `tr` turns the lines into space-delimited output, the outer parens make that into an array.  `$@` is the original input, and the rest of it slices the 0-indexed array from 1 and takes the next "array len - 2" chars.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LCoMwEEX3fsUFA00gAxpfoVDwP6wLK4rdRFrblfXbbTJFKLMZ7rmPW7dM@/h2/es@O4xOKqx7d5FCLsMDIoUw@OD1hDhd3Qn@lIqGfpohaoi1a@r2nJ6lFGsc/o2MUtu@RaNDggJAjCbRKDRSDaORaeRtoJTBMiUvWQ3ykLwn@XdysNSoOJL740h@lOTHRHCyYmF@iuWSiuMFV2W/XQOqeDcMeh72yWPyLirb/Qs)

(NOTE: not all test cases work on TIO for reasons i don't understand, but they do work on my local machine)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 99 bytes

```cs
a=>b=>new[]{a,b}.Concat(b>a?Enumerable.Range(a+1,b+~a):Enumerable.Range(b+1,a!=b?a+~b:0).Reverse())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZLBSgMxEIbv@xRj8ZCh26VWxdJ1t4eiolSQevBQepjEaQlss5pkK1K2r75GFGr15MJAhn/@byYho1xPlZabymmzgsd353mdTLV5TaMDaVIWBSuvS@OSGzZstTp0pNFLJQutQBXkHDxsI/gWnCcfjk2pn@GetBHO28DNF0B25RCCEyahb1lw8mS15zCexXFnDtsvZ3JXBqoTQ4il6KM4R6xh0cH0f2TvFMWwHXqGIdqSLa87RDFo@dABit7Fnq1//8V1ZdSlNj7@kd1emWrNlmTBn0Ke57CErKEsl1lu@G2@2FIs67AJRpEXMqfxnkhmZFYsqHsSy@6OcPSnJEOJjjI5pu5OjvqYzHjD1rFAbNKobj4A)

First (and probably last) time golfing in C#.

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), 68 bytes

```fs
let f x y=
 let s=if x<y then 1 else-1
 Seq.append[x;y][x+s..s..y-s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc6xCsIwFAXQPV9xKQgNkmBrxYJ2cHdzLB0EEwzUJPoyJF8f2x9o4A33woH7NImPsy7nWQVoRKSBYc00mKVeE8JbWTRQMynRMDzUVz69V/Y1xkuaxrgnKZdLgqbsf8YGbVHtbhXqlQZ3NxRqjQNOnLMNII7ot0WHrgQKGz3awhMtxJnz/Ac)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 1.0.1](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
=[‿|₌‿⁂JU
```

Don't even think about trying it Online.

### Explained

The output for this challenge is the two input numbers paired together joined with the range between those two numbers. However, there can't be any duplicates in the joined list, so it needs to be uniquified by order of appearance. But we also need to make sure that the two numbers aren't the same: otherwise, a singleton will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

## [F#](https://fsharp.org/), 67 bytes

```
let f x y=if(y-x<0)then[x;y]@List.rev[y+1..x-1]else[x;y]@[x+1..y-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc4xa8MwFATg3b/iMAQSioydpiTQ2HTp1qHQ0fXg2E9UoCiJLIoE/e@uosiDxu@edByf2HDRNM@SDDgsXC342jF7LDfmh1RrX1339iEmU2j6bd1TVRSWVR3JiR631t4z57PQcdVCGenfQ9YZIPHX4ItuhTCksQ5Xjnw1It/48@JvlWdZe3xXRrvPi8@aLru3nXuh0Icirx6131jiJfoUzJ5xiMEQgh120WP08oGCD9hG80fBFmy/jAnT@0SnREOiMREl4l7l/A8)

Appends a list containing x and y and a list iterating from x+1 to y-1 (if positive) or a list in reverse iteration order from y+1 to x-1 (if negative)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, 46 bytes

```perl
/ /;$_.=join$",'',$`+1..$'-1,reverse$'+1..$`-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchBCoAgEADAu69YYsFDrmkpCdETekNdPBSRotHz26A5To7l9MwddBOuej7SfmGjpFS4tVZrlGRViU8sNaL8ZyPLbMALGiCIAL2gHmgUDtyb8r2nqzItXhtrmPL5AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>30</s> <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
$[x,y][p:@[x,y]p++--x..y p]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?35KrPw)

```
$[x,y][               ; a function taking arguments x and y
    p: @[x,y]         ; assign the list [x,y] to p
    p ++              ; append something to p
    --x..y p          ; the range x to y without p
]                     ; end function, implicit return
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/)*, 33 bytes

```sh
A=({$1..$2});<<<$@\ ;<<<${A:1:-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5NboMwGET3nGKqskgWtsFNlRSIFO6BVEXwYSMVG/lnE8LZKbB5M3qzmZfXq6cAZkHO/ToK0RngExM56BAmXwgxWmP99Gyp29ufVZE8b@0oZCYzkV1FNMENSpGjjgX3nDwbDHt5LcA5hyHqECyiJwQ9eIzWEWwfyHwk/ek8R7NfqBO19bW@n@Y05zyVy7msqip9NDhyrou8YPmyLiW12pYK6eMdHFiHpjFLkvS44Gdjhu@N7Au3Q10O7uoGuQ8S7Lr@Aw)

(*) Using `set -o err_return`

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>87</del> 75 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU49a8MwEN31K94ogZTEiRMHgQMdC@0UOoUMUmIHF1dOZVEIJb/dPWuxmnY4uHf3vvqTac3Q2ffqFPBqGodvBpyrGh8EuPGXXuPJe3M77INv3OUoNN5cE1ASk7Ev06LW/NkFSSPK3b76PNB2RDlwIy1djNZWa97U3Oys4Aahg4W9qUzMzr678kxUbV9ND0wPMQvdS9OHAVcKD63jNV9IrIXAfI7xE6FEJrGUWEnkgvojoSs6bhN@xBKK6IpUi1QbrTYSxaNJPhpPHvk/OfnvWhE@UCh2mVC2MbeIieuYvvpTfmxZpO3jgYbqKlIoEqrNKLuzOxt@AA)

```scala
(a,b)=>a::b::(if(a>b)(a to b by-1).drop(1)else(a to b by 1).drop(1)).toList
```

Ungolfed version.

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val f = (a: Int, b: Int) => {
      a :: b :: (if (a > b) (a to b by -1).drop(1) else (a to b by 1).drop(1)).toList
    }
    println(f(0, 5)) // List(0, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4)
    println(f(-3, 8)) // List(-3, 8, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
    println(f(4, 4)) // List(4, 4)
    println(f(4, 5)) // List(4, 5)
    println(f(8, 2)) // List(8, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3)
    println(f(-2, -7)) // List(-2, -7, -3, -4, -5, -6)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ẸIḣṫḥ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWax_u2uH5cMfihztXP9yxdElxUnIxVGbB0mgLHaNYCAcA)

##### Explanation

```python
ẸIḣṫḥ  # Implicit input   ->  [8, 2]
Ẹ      # Dump onto stack  ->  8, 2
 I     # Inclusive range  ->  [8,7,6,5,4,3,2]
  ḣ    # Remove head      ->  [7,6,5,4,3,2]
   ṫ   # Remove tail      ->  [7,6,5,4,3]
    ḥ  # Concatenate      ->  [8,2,7,6,5,4,3]
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
ṡÞẇJ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLhuaHDnuG6h0oiLCIiLCIyXG44Il0=) (inputs are swapped)

```
ṡ    # Inclusive range
 Þẇ  # Push [first, last] and rest
   J # Concatenate
```

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript (ES6), 76 bytes**

`(a,b,c=[a,b])=>{c[c.length]=a<b?++a:--a;return a==b?(c.pop()+1&&c):f(a,b,c)}`

invocation should not pass the third argument: `f(-9,9)`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcy9DsIgEADgvU/h1HDhJ3Fs9eyDNB2OE6qGAKHYpfHZ0cTp274X7bRxeeaqLVkXdEx31zw2QcoqxvnHAng7eGYTXFzrY0G62klKGrWmS3H1XeKJEO0k2OSUBchz3zOM/n/Ap3GKWwrOhLQKL/SgBoCua18)

im still thinking...

Comment: Fails for input `4,4`

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 22 bytes

```
nnsaRl=[pr0]pu' oru' o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z8vrzgxKMc2uqDIILagVF0hvwhE/P9vwGUKAA)

The tricky bits here are that the range function in `Ly` only works if the start/end are sorted.  So the code has to conditionally flip the sequence of numbers before printing them.

```
nna                    - read in the start/end, stash the 2nd number
   aR                  - sort and generate the inclusive range
     l=                - does the 2nd number match the max of the range?
       [p 0]p          - "then" clause
         r             - reverse the stack
             u' o      - output the starting number and a space
                 r     - reverse the stack
                  u' o - output the ending number
                       - the sequence left on the stack prints automatically
```